# Create database within Azure SQL elastic pool takes almost 10 minutes to complete

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

We use Azure SQL databases and an elastic pool (level "Standard").

Usually the creation of a new customer database takes approximately 1-2 minutes but suddenly it started taking way longer (up to 10 minutes) and I have no idea why this is happening. I checked the pool in the Azure portal and everything seems fine. We are still far away from reaching the given limits (257/500 databases; ~11GB/200GB data size). Upscaling for a short period of time has no effect.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: You can contact the Azure customer support, but they pretty much will say that this is normal. As far as I know there isn't any SLA for bringing up a new DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some ongoing issue at Microsoft cloud services just check if your issue related to that, if that’s true your issue should be temporary